# Determine word size of my processor

Tags: c, processor, word-size

How do I determine the word size of my CPU? If I understand correct an `int` should be one word right? I'm not sure if I am correct.

So should just printing `sizeof(int)` would be enough to determine the word size of my processor?

Comment: OS specific, or cross platform?

Comment: note that `sizeof` returns a number of chars, and the standard only specifies **at least** 8 bits per char.

Comment: sizeof(int) works for every platform I've worked on.

Comment: Reading the answers, I think there is lack of clarity as to what you mean by "word size" -- size of registers, size of bus, and for what operations?

Comment: @Soren I think by word size they meant the number of bytes a processor can read in one CPU cycle. Usually, a system having a 32-bit processor reads 4 bytes in a CPU cycle and a 64-bit processor reads 8 bytes in a CPU cycle.

Answer (score 24):

Your assumption about sizeof(int) is untrue; see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models).

Since you must know the processor, OS and compiler at compilation time, the word size can be inferred using predefined [architecture/OS/compiler macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/) provided by the compiler.

However while on simpler and most RISC processors, word size, bus width, register size and memory organisation are often consistently one value, this may not be true to more complex CISC and DSP architectures with various sizes for floating point registers, accumulators, bus width, cache width, general purpose registers etc.

Of course it begs the question why you might need to know this?  Generally you would use the type appropriate to the application, and trust the compiler to provide any optimisation.  If optimisation is what you think you need this information for, then you would probably be better off using the [C99  'fast' types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Fixed_width_integer_types).  If you need to optimise a specific algorithm, implement it for a number of types and profile it.

Comment: I fixed the broken/incorrect links if anyone was confused before!

Comment: On x86-64 Linux, `int_fast16_t` and `int_fast32_t` are both `int64_t`, which is probably not an ideal choice.  32bit is the fastest for some cases, and makes smaller code (fewer REX prefixes).  If you're ever storing them in memory, esp. in an array, you definitely don't want a 64bit type using twice as much cache.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Agreed - the words 'generally' and 'probably' were used quite deliberately in the answer. As with any 'hand optimisation' it should be tested and compared to the straightforward solution.  Too bad the OP did not choose to clarify his need to know, or ask the X to this Y question.

Answer (score 14):

> an int should be one word right?

As I understand it, that depends on the data size model. For an explanation for UNIX Systems, [64-bit and Data Size Neutrality](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html). For example Linux 32-bit is ILP32, and Linux 64-bit is LP64. I am not sure about the difference across Window systems and versions, other than I believe all 32-bit Window systems are  ILP32.

> How do I determine the word size of my CPU?

That depends. Which version of C standard are you assuming. What platforms are we talking. Is this a compile or run time determination you're trying to make.

The C header file `<limits.h>` may defines `WORD_BIT` and/or `__WORDSIZE`.

Comment: These things are determined by the compiler and don't have a directly relationship to the actual size (width) of the CPU's word size.  Said another way, these things are defined by the compiler developer, not determined by the physical characteristics of the CPU itself.

Comment: Such as a cross-compiler environment, true. I should of clarified that if someone wants to write code that is aware of the word size of their *target* host, they can use something the limits.h header file.

Comment: This of course is for the target environment, not the _capabilities_ of the target CPU. Such as any late model x86 from Intel or AMD, that is capable of being used either as a 32 or 64-bit processor. Depending on the OS being run the CPU may be utilized as either a 32 or 64-bit processor. In 32-bit mode, the registers cannot be access as 64-bit (8 byte) _word_ registers, even though the CPU has 64-bit registers.

Comment: `__WORDSIZE` is 32 in the [x86-64 Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (ILP32 in 64bit mode with a register-call ABI), so that's not it, either.  `__SYSCALL_WORDSIZE` is 64 with `-mx32` and `-m64`, though.  It's not defined at all with `-m32`, so it's not usable either, and is probably a Linux or glibc-specific thing.

Answer (score 8):

sizeof(int) is not always the "word" size of your CPU.    The most important question here is ***why*** you want to know the word size.... are you trying to do some kind of run-time and CPU specific optimization?

That being said, on Windows with Intel processors, the nominal word size will be either 32 or 64 bits and you can easily figure this out:

- if your program is compiled for 32-bits, then the nominal word size is 32-bits
- if you have compiled a 64-bit program then then the nominal word size is 64-bits.

This answer sounds trite, but its true to the first order.  But there are some important subtleties.  Even though the x86 registers on a modern Intel or AMD processor are 64-bits wide; you can only (easily) use their 32-bit widths in 32-bit programs - even though you may be running a 64-bit operating system.  This will be true on Linux and OSX as well.

Moreover, on most modern CPU's the data bus width is wider than the standard ALU registers (EAX, EBX, ECX, etc).   This bus width can vary, some systems have 128 bit, or even 192 bit wide busses.

If you are concerned about performance, then you also need to understand how the L1 and L2 data caches work.  Note that some modern CPU's have an L3 cache.   Caches including a unit called the Write Buffer

Comment: isn't sizeof(int) done at compile time, which means that it's the size it's compiled for, not the size of the computer that's running it?

Comment: 32bit x86 code literally can't use the full-width 64bit registers.  There's no operand-size prefix or anything.  Also, are you sure about 192 bit wide data paths in any CPUs?  That sounds like the memory bus width in a GPU.  Intel went from 128b paths from L1 to execution units to 256b (in Haswell, released years after this answer was written).

Answer (score 3):

Make a program that does some kind of integer operation many times, like an integer version of the SAXPY algorithm. Run it for different word sizes, from 8 to 64 bits (i.e. from `char` to `long long`).

Measure the time each version spends while running the algorithm. If there is one specific version that lasts noticeably less than the others, the word size used for that version is probably the native word size of your computer. On the other way, if there are several versions that last more or less the same time, pick up the one which has the greater word size.

Note that even with this technique you can get false data: your benchmark, compiled using Turbo C and running on a 80386 processor through DOS will report that the word size is 16 bits, just because the compiler doesn't use the 32-bit registers to perform integer aritmetic, but calls to internal functions that do the 32-bit version of each aritmetic operation.

Comment: I can't think of a use case where anyone would want to determine processor word size at run time via this method.  Processor is fixed so this should be determined at compile time or use a platform/OS specific method if runtime is required.

Comment: Compile time tests are limited to the use of sizeof operator and the like, which yields the size in bytes for several data types, not necessary identical to the native word size. This (empiric) method does not need specific platform/OS support. Ir relays on the basis that integer operations using the native word size are execute faster. A 32-bit processor can use 8, 16, 32 and 64-bit data, and will spend about the same time for 8, 16 and 32 bit data, but aritmetic operations will need more cycles to do the same job for 64 bit operations, so one can conclude that the native word size is 32 bits

Comment: I don't think there is a use case to empirically determine the word size.  Platforms typically provide macro definitions to use at compile time.

Comment: Make sure to account for cache effects (wider types can appear slower because of increased memory bandwidth demands, not because of taking multiple instructions).  e.g. loop repeatedly over the same small buffer, to make sure it's cached.  Or do something like `a += b; b += a;` (Fibonacci) several million times (with `unsigned` types, because it *will* overflow).  It's unlikely to get optimized away, and doesn't depend on memory.

Comment: I'd argue that finding the word-size as 16 bits for Turbo C is the correct result.  If the compiler doesn't use them, it doesn't matter that the machine has them.  You're measuring the word-size of the compiler's target, which is what affects the decision to use `uint16_t` vs. `uint32_t` vs. `uint64_t` vs. `__uint128_t`.

Comment: @ConorPatrick: Building a binary with several implementations of a function and benchmarking them once at startup is a valid strategy.  Maybe only as a fallback for platforms your CPP macros don't handle, or for platforms where there aren't reliable macros.  Linux uses this strategy for software RAID5/RAID6: there are several SSE/AVX implementations that all get compiled in for x86, and it chooses the fastest one at boot time (or module-load time).

Answer (score 2):

*"Additionally, the **size of the C type long is equal to the word size**, whereas the size of the int type is sometimes less than that of the word size. For example, the Alpha has a 64-bit word size. Consequently, registers, pointers, and the long type are 64 bits in length."*

source: http://books.msspace.net/mirrorbooks/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch19lev1sec2.html

Keeping this in mind, the following program can be executed to find out the word size of the machine you're working on-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{

    long l;
    
    short s = (8 * sizeof(l));
    
    printf("Word size of this machine is %hi bits\n", s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: There's no good way. The original idea behind the C data types was that int would be the fastest (native) integer type, long the biggest etc.

Then came operating systems that originated on one CPU and were then ported to different CPUs whose native word size was different. To maintain source code compatibility, some of the OSes broke with that definition and kept the data types at their old sizes, and added new, non-standard ones.

That said, depending on what you actually need, you might find some useful data types in `stdint.h`, or compiler-specific or platform-specific macros for various purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To use at compile time: `sizeof(void*)`

Comment: This is not correct on platforms like 360 and PS3 which are 64-bit, but pointers are 32-bit (ABI quirk to conserve space).

Comment: That would give to the size of a pointer, which is something different

Answer (score 0):

What every may be the reason for knowing the size of the processor it don't matter.

The size of the processor is the amount of date that Arthematic Logic Unit(ALU) of One CPU Core can work on at a single point of time. A CPU Cores's ALU will on Accumulator Register at any time. So, The size of a CPU in bits is the the size of Accumulator Register in bits.

You can find the size of the accumulator from the data sheet of the processor or by writing a small assembly language program.

Note that the effective usable size of Accumulator Register can change in some processors (like ARM) based on mode of operations (Thumb and ARM modes). That means the size of the processor will also change based on the mode for that processors.

It common in many architectures to have virtual address pointer size and integer size same as accumulator size. It is only to take advantage of Accumulator Register in different processor operations but it is not a hard rule.

Answer (score 0):

Many thinks of memory as an array of bytes. But CPU has another view of it. Which is about memory granularity. Depending on architecture, there would be 2, 4, 8, 16 or even 32 bytes memory granularity. Memory granularity and address alignment have great impact on performance, stability and correctness of software. Consider a granularity of 4 bytes and an unaligned memory access to read in 4 bytes. In this case every read, 75% if address is increasing by one byte, takes two more read instructions plus two shift operations and finally a bitwise instruction for final result which is performance killer. Further atomic operations could be affected as they must be indivisible. Other side effects would be caches, synchronization protocols, cpu internal bus traffic, cpu write buffer and you guess what else. A practical test could be run on a circular buffer to see how the results could be different. CPUs from different manufacturers, based on model, have different registers which will be used in general and specific operations. For example modern CPUs have extensions with 128 bits registers. So, the word size is not only about type of operation but memory granularity. Word size and address alignment are beasts which must be taken care about. There are some CPUs in market which does not take care of address alignment and simply ignore it if provided. And guess what happens?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, how are you interested in calculating this value? There are a lot of variables.

sizeof(int) != sizeof(word). the size of byte, word, double word, etc have never changed since their creation for the sake of API compatibility in the windows api world at least. Even though a processor word size is the natural size an instruction can operate on. For example, in msvc/cpp/c#, sizeof(int) is four bytes. Even in 64bit compilation mode. Msvc/cpp has __int64 and c# has Int64/UInt64(non CLS compliant) ValueType's. There are also type definitions for WORD DWORD and QWORD in the win32 API that have never changed from two bytes, four bytes, and eight bytes respectively. As well as UINT/INT_PTR on Win32 and UIntPtr/IntPtr on c# that are guranteed to be big enough to represent a memory address and a reference type respectively. AFAIK, and I could be wrong if arch's still exist, I don't think anyone has to deal with, nor do, near/far pointers exist anymore, so if you're on c/cpp/c#, sizeof(void*) and Unsafe.SizeOf{IntPtr}() would be enough to determine your maximum "word" size I would think in a compliant cross-platform way, and if anyone can correct that, please do so! Also, sizes of intrinsic types in c/cpp are vague in size definition.

[C data type sizes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C_data_types&oldid=376652910#Size)