# How to set a constant in my program that will be dependent on the platform

Tags: c, garbage-collection, bit-manipulation

We are writing a program that allocates and frees memory automatically, a garbage collector in other words. It should work in a 64-bit machine and 32-bit machine without having to go in and change the code. This means that our bitwise functions cannot have a, for example, `x << 63`, since this would crash in a 32 bit machine. 
So what we need is a constant that is set when the program is compiled and it should be either the length of pointer or an `uintptr_t` that will be either 4 bytes or 8 bytes long depending on the platform and use these as a starting point.

I hope my question was clear, it wasn't easy to formulate it.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` gives you the number of bits per `char`, `sizeof` gives you the number of `char`s per variable/type.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2401756/694576 if not a duplicate to.

Comment: `#define DM_CONSTANT (sizeof (void*)*CHAR_BIT)`

Comment: "I hope my question was clear" --> posting a sample code usage would add clarity.

Comment: What kind of program has your GC, on what kind of operating system and compiler and processor?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pre-processor directives? As such:

```
#ifdef SYSTEM_32_BITS
   int * myPtr = 0x00;
#elseif SYSTEM_64_BITS
   long myVal = 0;
#endif
```

You can define one system and the other parameter would not compile. Would that work out for you?

Comment: Note that preprocessor defines have to be identifiers and identifiers can't start with a digit, so you'd need to use some name other than `32BIT_SYSTEM` — maybe `SYSTEM_32_BITS` vs `SYSTEM_64_BITS` (which leaves open 128-bit and 16-bit systems for future expansion or historic contraction).

Answer (score 1):

You can use sizeof to do this.  E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static const size_t ptr_size = sizeof(int*);
static const size_t ptr2_size = sizeof(uintptr_t);

int main() {

    printf("int*: %zu\n", ptr_size);
    printf("uintptr_t: %zu\n", ptr2_size);

    return 0;
}
```

This will give you the following on a 64-bit platform:

```
int*: 8
uintptr_t: 8
```

Comment: The `sizeof`-operator evaluates to an `size_t` not to an `uint32_t`.

Comment: OK, doing something a little dirty to avoid warnings under 32-bit platforms where size_t would be an unsigned int not the unsigned long int on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: `(uint32_t)` cast serves scant purpose.  Use `"%u"` with `unsigned` and `"%" PRIu32` with `uint32_t`.

Comment: `static const size_t ptr_size = sizeof(int*); printf("int*: %zu\n", ptr_size);` would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, you learn something new everyday. I didn't realise there was a format specifier for size_t.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) (and its `intptr_t`) and [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). Both are specified by C11 standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). You could use `INTPTR_MAX` (and/or  `INTPTR_WIDTH`, the latter being specific to some implementations, like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), which are preprocessor constants.

You could use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) trick to autodetect at build time (e.g. with [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)) if you have a 64 or a 32 bits system (so generate something with preprocessor flags), and this is very common. You could also use [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

> We are writing a [...] garbage collector

Writing an efficient GC could be difficult and is time-consuming (and generally requires some compiler and operating-system specific code). Did you consider using some *existing* library for GC, e.g. [Boehm GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) or [MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/)?

Comment: Indeed. `INTPTR_WIDTH` is on GCC. However, a garbage collector is probably tied to a particular implementation in practice...