# How to compute the word size of your computer in C?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine word size of my processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301007/determine-word-size-of-my-processor)

It is One Interview question today. But I didn't know ...

---

I think the interviewer meaned the word size of cpu.

---

I find an answer like this:

```
int cpu_bits(void *dummy1, void *dummy2) 
{ 
 long offset = (long)&dummy2 - (long)&dummy1; 
 int ret = 0; 
 if (8 == offset) 
     ret = 64; 
 else if (4 == offset) 
     ret = 32; 
 else if (2 == offset) 
     ret = 16; 
 else if (1 == offset) 
     ret = 8; 
 else 
     ret = -1; 
 return ret;  
} 

int main() 
{ 
 printf("%d\n", cpu_bits(NULL, NULL)); 
 return 0; 
}
```

The result seems to be right, Do you think so ?

Comment: I would begin the answer by asking the interviewer for the **exact definition** of word size that they had in mind...

Comment: @PaulR What if the word size if 8 bits? In C, int is always at least 16 bits.

Comment: @Juho: yes, I've withdrawn my answer and comments now that I've had time to think about it... ;-)

Comment: @wong2 Yes, thank U ! It's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: the standard does not define a data type that is guaranteed to correspond to the word size of the underlying architecture, and what "word size" means on modern CPU's is quite a vague thing: [Word Size versus Address Size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Word_size_versus_address_size).

With current processors having compatibility modes, registers of a different size, advanced addressing modes and instructions suited for data of various widths, talking of a general "word size" is imprecise, to say the least.

I suppose the interviewer is still living in the 90's and remembers the dubiously called `WORD` and `DWORD` types that were introduced by WinAPI when most computers were still 16-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think they were expecting something like this:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
```

Comment: sizeof(int) does not work if the word size is 8 bits. Also, in most 64-bit compilers int is 32-bit while the word is 64 bits.

Comment: @PaulR: we've hit a race condition with our posts and edits. :)

Comment: @Juho: what do you mean it doesn't work? Btw, int must be at least 16 bits long per the C standard. Figuring out the underlying, hardware, word size is probably something that you can't do reliably in C.

Comment: @Alex: don't cast the expression to `int`, there's the `%zu` modifier to print a value of type `size_t`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: I always forget about z, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Alex: What I meant is that sizeof(int) does not always return the machine word size since int is not always the same as machine word. On 8-bit processors int is probably 16-bit while word is 8-bit. Same goes for most x86_64 compilers where int is 32-bit and word is 64 bits.

Comment: This is evaluated at compile time :-)

Comment: @Juho: I know that full well. Should we then call the interviewers idiots for asking such questions or do you think it was an intended trick question?

Comment: @Alex: I guess I would explain that this is impossible to do correctly on every processor/compiler. Then again, I'm not very good in job interviews. I hope this was an intended trick question, since otherwise the interviewer would have been an idiot.