# Can sizeof(pointer) be used to find the machine type

Tags: c

```
if(sizeof(pointer) == 4) /* 4*8 = 32 bits */ 
printf("32 bit machine");

if(sizeof(pointer) == 8) /* 8*8 = 64 bits */
printf("64 bit machine");
```

Is this confirmed across any platform?
I mean can we rely on the above check to identify which machine type it is?

Since pointer is basically used to store the memory location in a 32 bit machine it should be 4 bytes and 64 bit machine it should be 8 bytes?

Is there a possibility that the `sizeof(pointer) < 4` on a 32 bit machine.( 1 word is 32 bits architecture)

Comment: Size of a *pointer* should be 64 bit on 64-bit machines, I'm not sure about the size of an `int`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths No this is not what I want I meant can I rely on the above conditions? Not other way to check my machine

Comment: @Gopi: And the answers to the linked question go into that. Terms like "32 bit machine" and "64 bit machine" are poorly-defined to begin with, so an answer for "any platform" fails to make it out of the door.

Comment: Moreover, looking for a completely portable way to detect some poorly-defined machine characteristic looks suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In the first case, you're better off writing standard programs that work on any platform. In the second, you're better off focusing on what specific difference you are interested in (like the size of a `long`, which you can get easily) rather than making assumptions about what "64 bit machine" might mean.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Did anyone drop the int word?^^

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility that the sizeof(pointer) < 4 on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: @chux Then if the memory location i 32 bit wide than how is it stored in the pointer?

Comment: The amount of memory and the native integer width of the processor are separate issues.

Comment: C was designed to be portable, while it lets you do low-level stuff, there's a lot of nitty-gritty things abstracted away. Determining the architecture your program is running on is something that the language isn't really suited for. Just look into what your compiler can do to help you with this (ie: gcc's `__x86_64__` and `_____LP64_____` macro's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the definition of an *x*-bit machine a bit vague to begin with. The most common definition I know of is that *x* is the number of bits for a general-purpose register of that machine.

Take the 8086 as an example: it's widely considered to be a 16-bit machine since it's registers are 16 bits wide. Yet a pointer is formed by combining two registers which yields a 20-bit address (since 20/8 == 2.5 I guess compilers would round up to 3 or 4 bytes; it's up to the compiler).

[The C standard even allows pointers to different types to be of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296235/sizeof-pointer-differs-for-data-type-on-same-architecture?rq=1). So it's possible that `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(myFunction)`, for example.

Also, some machines support different modes, like x86-64 machines support executing x86-32 code. This further complicates things. And then there's this weird old thing called *near* and *far* pointers: [pointers in Turbo C for x86-16 thus were 2 byte or 4 byte wide, depending on what they pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474076/400056). And the [Open Watcom compiler can give you 6-byte pointers on x86-32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/399999/400056) if it's defined to be *far*.

Last but not least there's the *char size*. It's defined to be 1. But how many *bits* make up a char is a different thing: the `CHAR_BIT` macro tells you and it's usually 8, but on some DSPs today and some former CPUs it could be values like 7, 9, 16, or even more. If `CHAR_BIT` is 16 and a pointer is 32 bit wide, then `sizeof(void*) == 2` on such a machine.

So you **cannot** rely on `sizeof(pointer)` to determine the machine's "CPU size"… but in practice, this is often Good Enough™. It depends on *why* you want/need the information.

Comment: I wanted this info to know what is the word size. Number of bits fetched by cpu in one cycle.  But it seems like I should not be relying on this.

Comment: Aha, this is a different question but almost as hard :-) I'm afraid there is no portable way to query that in C. The standard does not define any type to be required to be of "word" size. Depending on the compiler, there may be macros that tell you but it's not something that can be queried in a portable manner.

Comment: See also answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711836/how-to-compute-the-word-size-of-your-computer-in-c?lq=1) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301007/determine-word-size-of-my-processor).

Answer (score 1):

This certainly gives you the size of a pointer, and by that the theoretical maximum of memory that can be addressed in the current CPU mode.

However, not all bits in a pointer may actually be used in addressing: Current 64 bit CPUs use only 48 bits of a 64 bit pointer. Likewise, there were CPUs that used only 24 bits for addressing while storing pointers in 32 bit registers.

Also, the current CPU mode may not reflect the capabilities of the hardware: 64 bit CPUs have compatibility modes for 32 bit software. Such software will never be able to detect a 64 bit pointer.

Comment: So we can't rely on above check?

Comment: Not if the objective is to determine the CPU type. If the objective is to determine the current CPU mode, your check gives an upper limit, but no more. To get real information about the hardware, you must ask the kernel, for instance by parsing /proc/cpuinfo .