# what does Double word alignment mean?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

what is double word aligned data??. i am working on a Ti processor with the c6accel DSP engine.The fft function requires the input data array of samples to be double word aligned.what does double word aligned exactly mean and how do i generate it?

Comment: See: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/aligned.html

Answer (score 2):

A word is the amount of data which each register in the CPU is able to hold. This is dependant on the processor being used - on 32-bit systems this will be 32 bits, and on 64-bit systems this will be 64 bits, etc... Your TI processor will probably be either 16-bit or 32-bit depending on the model (guess based on [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Main_Page)).

The size of a word will generally correspond to the size of a pointer, although technically this is not guarenteed to be true (doesn't work on PS3/XB360) and as a result should not be relied on as a rule ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301007/determine-word-size-of-my-processor)). The correct way of determining the size of a world will depend on which operating system you're using. As quoted from the previous source:

> The C header file  may defines WORD_BIT and/or __WORDSIZE.

The size of a double word is just the size of a word * 2. Data in memory (RAM) is generally fetched by programs 1 word at a time assuming the fetch begins on a word boundary. If this is not the case the data on either side of the word boundary will need to be fetched in two separate instructions, which leads to inefficiencies since twice the amount of fetches need to be done and reading/writing to/from RAM is relatively slow (Sidenote: this is largely mitigated by caches in modern processors, although that's another topic altogether).

Answer (score 2):

For TI C6x: double word = 64-bit
Make sure your array starts at an address that is a multiple of 8 bytes.

You can use the assembly directive .align before declaring your array, or you can use the linker to link your array section at an aligned address. If you can't control the address (e.g. you have memory from malloc), make your array start after a few bytes (to the next 8 byte boundary).